# How do I access a string-indexed element of a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have the following array (in php after executing print_r on the array object):

```
Array ( 
   [#weight] => 0 
   [#value] => Some value.
)
```

Assuming the array object is `$arr`, how do I print out "value". The following does NOT work:

```
print  $arr->value;
print  $val ['value'] ;
print  $val [value] ;
```

So... how do you do it? Any insight into WHY would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `print $val['#value']`, since it looks like the key is not `value`, but `#value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo $arr['#value'];
```

The [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/print_r) appears to be telling you that the array key is the string `#value`.

Answer (score 1):

After quickly checking the docs, it looks like my comment was correct.

Try this code:

```
print $arr['#value'];
```

The reason is that the key to the array is not `value`, but `#value`.

Comment: I see now. I thought for some reason that the "#" meant its a pointer or a reference of some sort. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You said your array contains this :

```
Array ( 
   [#weight] => 0 
   [#value] => Some value.
)
```

So, what about using the keys given in [`print_r`](http://php.net/print_r)'s output, like this :

```
echo $arr['#value'];
```

What `print_r` gives is the couples of keys/values your array contains ; and to access a value in an array, you use `$your_array['the_key']`

You might want to take a look at the PHP manual ; here's the [page about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

*Going through the chapters about the basics of PHP might help you in the future :-)*